# Telerik Rad Controls Messy stylesheet after postbacks?

Tags: asp.net, telerik, rad-controls

Telerik Rad Controls css styling gets messed after multiple postbacks on page or in another case where multiple user controls in the page are using Telerik controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been through this although the solution is one line of code but I had a hard time to find it so I thought it's better to share it with u guys,

in every page or user control that u have that are using Telerik Rad Controls put the Following line in the Page_Load event

```
protected void Page_Load(Object sender,EvenArgs e)
{
RadControlName.EnableAjaxSkinRendering=true;

//for example if u have a Rad Combo box put
//RadCombo1.EnableAjaxSkinRendering=true;

}
```

I hope that would help